# First web server questions

Tags: web-server, email-server, domain-controller, bandwidth-control

Just looking for some help/suggestions with this. I require my own server for an upcoming project that will be hosting users websites. I want to build a control panel the user can log into and modify their website which will be stored elsewhere on the server. This all seems easy enough, It's just managing domains and emails that confuse me.

What should I look for to manage domain names and point them to the correct website and also what would be the best way to manage email accounts/set up new ones etc. I want to avoid cPanel/WHM if possible, I'm looking to control most things through the control panel I will be building. So any suggestions on this would be useful as well, as I will be wanting to add email accounts through php (Can be done using a shell I assume?).

I will also be wanting to measure bandwidth used on the websites contained in each users directory, any suggestions on making this possible?

I'm really looking for some suggestions on what software to use to set this up, any advice would be really helpful!

Thanks, Graeme

Comment: I'd recommend using one of the many pre-built hosted-server-control-panel software projects. Many are quite mature and full-featured

Comment: Have a look at infiniCloud I feel that the tools here will be available to help you get started with what you are looking for. https://cloud.logicworks.net

Managing Domains and Emails would be a matter of registering with a naming registrar such as GoDaddy and assigning as an enterprise user.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you would like to do this from scratch ? Using pre-built (and there are free ones available), you would be able to avoid security risks (because the pre-built ones are generally widely tested and bug-fixed)

Comment: I don't nessecarily want to build everything. I would like a management system that I can easily use, but I don't want to have a cPanel for every user, so that part I would rather have customized or built myself to only provide certain things and also the services I plan on offering. I am not building a web host as such, so I don't plan on offering all of the things you find in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) It should allow you to do a lot of this. There are some great guides on configuring it.